# How to update the screen with AngularJs with all components (Ionic)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I need help please. I have a component (select) to dynamically change the language on the settings page. This works, but when I change the language and refresh the page, the back button disappears (ng-click="$ionicGoBack()"). The button to return only appears when I go to the settings screen, but not the main screen. I'm using Ionic and Cordova.

How can I update the page with the language without losing the button to return? I appreciate the help of someone.

My code:

```
$scope.selecionaIdioma = function(idiom){

        console.log(localeConf.defaultLocale);
        localeConf.defaultLocale = idiom;
        console.log(localeConf);
        localStorage.setItem("appIdiom",idiom);  //change language

        window.localStorage.appIdioma = idioma; 
        window.location.reload();              //refresh the page
}
```

[image]

Comment: you haven't provided enough information to troubleshoot your question.  You are asking about a UI item disappearing (some button with an `ng-click`), but you haven't shown any of your UI layout, so it's not clear at all what is controlling the visibility of this item.  Beyond that, `window.location.reload()` probably isn't the best option in an angular application.

Comment: @Claies Do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: Sorry when I said layout I probably should have said HTML, the screenshot you posted doesn't add any information that shows how the button in question might be generated.  I still think it is related to window.reload, though

Comment: Thanks @Claies .. I think the problem is with the Ionic ..
The main problem is ...

1.User clicks something on a view that takes them to another state and shows a back button
2. if the user refreshes the page here then the back button no longer shows

Comment: well that would make sense, in general;  `window.location.reload` literally reloads the app, and starts it from scratch, which is the nature of Single Page Applications.  when the app starts from scratch, there is no previous view to go back to.

Answer (score 0):

I got as follows .. back to the home page and the user will have to return to the settings page but will be translated. I do not think is the best way but at the moment I will use this solution. I appreciate if anyone knew of any other to be better. I removed the "reload()" and added:

```
window.location.href = 'index.html';
```